# Base Class or Derived Class is Runtime Type?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I've been reading documentation about `virtual` methods :

> In a virtual method invocation, the run-time type of the instance for
>   which that invocation takes place determines the actual method
>   implementation to invoke. In a non-virtual method invocation, the
>   compile-time type of the instance is the determining factor. In
>   precise terms, when a method named N is invoked with an argument list
>   A on an instance with a compile-time type C and a run-time type R
>   (**where R is either C or a class derived from C**), the invocation is
>   processed as follows... :
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx

However, I noticed something which is bold above. Lets say we have a code like this:

```
class Planet{
  public string Name;
  public float Size;
  public virtual void SpinPlanet(){
     Console.WriteLine("Hoooraaay!!!");
  }
}

class Earth : Planet{

}
```

And somewhere in my code I do:

```
Earth world = new Earth();
world.SpinPlanet();
```

In this case:

- **N** is `SpinPlanet()`
- **C** is `Earth`
- **R** is `Planet`

So how come `R` can be derived class of compile-time type `C`. Aren't the base class types being resolved during run-time?

Comment: I think you've labeled C/R incorrectly - they would both be `Earth`. Your scenario would be `Planet world = new Earth();`

Comment: It says : "instance with a compile-time type C and a run-time type R" before the bold statement.

Comment: in "C world = new R()"  R can be either C or type derived from C. And C is compile time type of "world" and R is its run-time type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken- the compile-time type (C) is `Earth` *and* the run-time type (R) is *also* `Earth`.  The part of the specification that you point out is not really relevant here.

What is relevant is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691356(v=vs.71).aspx, specifically:

> The set of candidate methods for the method invocation is constructed.
>   Starting with the set of methods associated with M, which were found
>   by a previous member lookup (Section 7.3), the set is reduced to those
>   methods that are applicable with respect to the argument list A.

The only candidate implementation of `SpinPlanet` just happens to be in the base class of `Earth`, not in the derived class.

The part of the spec that you refer to would apply if the code were:

```
Planet world = new Earth();
world.SpinPlanet();
```

(especially if Earth defined an override for `SpinPlanet`) because then the compile type (the type of the variable) would be `Planet`, but the runtime type would be `Earth`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct *method to invoke* will be resolved at runtime, by picking it from [Virtual Methods Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). So if you add to `Earth`

```
class Earth : Planet{
   public override void SpinPlanet(){
     Console.WriteLine("Hoooraaay Earth!!!");
  }
}
```

on code like this

```
Planet world = new Earth();
world.SpinPlanet(); //even if declared type Planet, 
                    // the real type remain Earth, so its  method will be called
```

will be invoked `Earth's` method.

In *my* example compile time type is `Planet`, but runtime type is `Earth`.

In *your* example, the compile time and runtime types are the same `Earth`.

Comment: I am asking whether the bold statement is true?

Comment: @Braveyard: sure its true ! "In a virtual method invocation, the run-time type of the instance for which that invocation takes place determines the actual method implementation to invoke". *Exactly* what happens.

Comment: @Braveyard: I'm afraid you refer to the last part of the sentence provided in your question, but that one is in relation of *non* virtual methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems I am missing a lunch, my brain stopped :)